# Что делать если стобцы одной таблицы из разных баз данных имеют разный тип?

Tags: java, jdbc, odbc

Приложение работало с базой данных (БД1), затем появилась необходимость работать с еще одной базой данных от другого производителя(БД2) - они идентичные по названиям таблиц и их столбцов, но проблема в том что типы данных некоторых столбцов разные. 
К примеру есть столбец с типом данных БД1.date и БД2.date:

```
...
    ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select mydate from MyTable");
    rs.getDate(1); //возвращает дату если коннект к БД1 и SQLException если коннект к БД2
    rs.getTimestamp(1)//возвращает timestamp и для БД1 и БД2

...
```

Появилась идея написать что-то универсальное:

```
new Date(rs.getTimeStamp(1).getTime());
```

Но беда в том что есть куча мест в разных DAO, где придется `rs.getDate()` менять на строку выше, да и не факт что эта строка универсальна. 
Хотел создать свой класс `ResultSet extends JdbcOdbcResultSet`, и переопределить метод `getDate()`, а затем во всех классах исправить импорты, но downcasting в java вроде бы не работает и реализовать вот так не могу:

```
mypackage.ResultSet rs = (myPackage.ResultSet) rs.executeQuery(query);
```

Как вообще правильно поступать в таких случаях, когда не известно с какими еще базами данных придется работать, а типы возвращаемых данных могут не совпадать?

- P/S Производителей СУБД скрыл специально, чтобы понять общий подход в проектировании.

Comment: Можно завести набор классов, описывающих каноничное представление данных внутри программы. И писать DAO/адаптеры под каждую разновидность базы.

Comment: Дело в том что баз не две, а уже 4, и писать на каждую свой набор помоему не true.Все прекрасно работало через JdbcOdbc bridge, пока не появилась отечественная СУБД ЛИНТЕР, где Date оказался не Date.

Comment: Тогда вам тем более нужно отделить модель даных приложения от СУБД, описать интерфейсами DAO слой и реализовывать его отдельно под каждую СУБД.\

Comment: То есть нет никакого универсального подхода?

Comment: Это и есть универсальный поход: работать на уровне бизнес-логики с   конкретной моделью данных, отделяться от баз DAO-слоем, использовать ORM по мере необходимости.